# Set Icon Type by Button Click with Google Maps API3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a simple interactive map that will allow the user to select a marker type from a button outside the map, then place a single marker when the user clicks on the map. After the marker is dropped the user could reposition the map or select another marker type to add. I realize this is a pretty basic question but I just started learning.  An example would be much appreciated as I am still learning the terminology. Thanks!

Here is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple SITTEMP</title>   
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing" async defer>
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="height:100%">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var map;
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.401942, -110.663985);
            var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
}
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
};
        function placeMarker(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
});
}
</script>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%;"></div>
    <button id= "blueButton"> Add Blue Marker</button>
    <button id= "redButton"> Add Red Marker</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple One:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple SITTEMP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDTQxCH5Vw9ot8amZ-3dG66_joi2mzpJqI&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing" async defer>
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="height:100%">
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.401942, -110.663985);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

var markerIcon = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png';
function setMarkerIconColor(color){
    if (color == "blue") {markerIcon = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_blue.png'};
    if (color == "red") {markerIcon = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png'};
}
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        icon: markerIcon,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
    });
}

</script>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%;"></div>
    <button id= "blueButton" onclick="setMarkerIconColor('blue')"> Add blue Marker </button>
    <button id= "redButton" onclick="setMarkerIconColor('red')"> Add Red Marker</button>
</body>
</html>
```